# ASP.NET MVC Remote Validation: Return boolean and string

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, string, validation

I have been attempting to use ASP.NET MVC remote validation for username login access to return both a string and a boolean. If I return just a string, it will assume a boolean of false and not let the user submit the form. Is there a way I could pass in both true and a string such as "[USERNAME] is available!"?

Current method:

```
public JsonResult isUserAvailable(string username)
    {
        if (Membership.GetUser(username) == null)
        {
            return Json(String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<strong style='color: green;'>{0} is available!</strong>", 
                username), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        else
        {
            return Json(false, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Furqan suggested the data you are returning is not Json but Html.

I suggest  that you either return a Json object or a different ActionResult, perhaps `ContentResult`. This [blog post](http://brendan.enrick.com/post/Types-of-ASPNET-MVC-3-Action-Results.aspx) does a good job of explaining the different `ActionResult` types.

Answer (score 1):

Use Json object to send the data back, modify your else block like this and consume JSON on client

```
 else
    {
       var data = new 
       { 
         result = false, 
         userName = username 
       };
 return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
```